# Show that $\mathcal{F}_{X}$ is the smallest $\sigma-$field containing the inverse images $X^{-1}(B)$ of all Borel sets $B$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

I am currently working on the following problem for my measure theory course and I wanted some feedback on my work:

> Show that $\mathcal{F}_{X}$ is the smallest $\sigma-$field containing the inverse images $X^{-1}(B)$ of all Borel sets $B$ (note that $\mathcal{F}_X :=\{S \subset \mathcal{F}:S = X^{-1}(B),\text{for some} \ B \in \mathcal{B} \}$ where $X$ is a random variable and $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ is a probability space).

My (short) work is as follows:

Take any $\sigma-$field $\mathcal{L} := \{S \subset \mathcal{F}:S = X^{-1}(B), B \in \mathcal{B} \}$. Then we can see that $\mathcal{F}_X \subset \mathcal{L}$ (since $\mathcal{F}_X$ is defined for *some* Borel sets $B$), hence $\mathcal{F}_X$ is the smallest $\sigma-$field containing the inverse images $X^{-1}(B)$ of all Borel sets $B$.

---

My question regarding my work: my professor said everything looks good but I need to justify that $\mathcal{L}$ is in fact a sigma-field (which I thought to be given). Is there any easier way to show this without going through the requirements for a set to constitute a sigma-field? Regardless, any tips or feedback of any kind is welcome.

Comment: In $\mathcal{F}_X$ we range over *all* $B \in \mathcal{B}$, not *some*, what do you mean?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma - Thats what I figured as well, but in my textbook it gives the definition that way. if $\mathcal{F}_X$ ranges over all $B \in \mathcal{B}$, how come we can ask whether or not it is the minimal one that contains all inverse images under $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite clear that $$\mathcal{F}_X:=\{X^{-1}[B]\mid B \in \mathcal{B}\}$$

is a $\sigma$-field, because $\mathcal{B}$ is one and we have identities like

$$X^{-1}[\bigcup_n B_n]=\bigcup_n X^{-1}[B_n]; X^{-1}[B^\complement] = \Omega\setminus X^{-1}[B]; X^{-1}[\bigcap_n B_n]=\bigcap_n X^{-1}[B_n]$$

This is a trivial verification. And it's trivially the *minimal* one that contains all inverse images under $X$ of all Borel sets. If $X$ is measurable, it's a sub-$\sigma$-field of $\mathcal{F}$.